# How to add the error indicator in table?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, syntax

Consider some function

```
function[mass_,lifetime_]:=NDSolve[{equations[mass,lifetime], initialconditions},functions,{t,t0,tmax}]
```

Let us assume that there is some kind of numeric instability in this function related to the syntax I used. Namely, for some values of parameters (like mass = 0.05, lifetime = 0.03), it is evaluated without any problems (apart from some warnings which may be neglected), but for some very similar values (like mass = 0.05, lifetime = 0.0301) it returns an error like

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 50000 steps reached at the point t ==
>
> ```
> 0.00521324.
> ```

I need to make a table

```
table = Flatten[Table[{mass,lifetime,function[mass,lifetime]},{mass,massvalues},{lifetime,lifetimevalues}],{2,1}]
```

Is it possible to re-define the table such that rows with the error will be marked somehow?

Like

```
tableModified = Flatten[Table[{mass,lifetime,label,function[mass,lifetime]},{mass,massvalues},{lifetime,lifetimevalues}],{2,1}]
```

for which `label = 1` if the mentioned error has not occurred and `label = 0` if the error has occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Check`. For example:

`Check[{tmp1=SomeCode,1},{tmp1,0},MessageName];`

Comment: Thank you. But will it work for arbitrary details of message (maximum number of steps reached at different times)?

Comment: @JohnTaylor If you want to check any message, you can omit the last argument of `Check` (that is, MessageName).